# Alternative for Dragonfly except Firebug

Tags: firebug, opera-dragonfly

What is the alternative for Dragonfly except Firebug for opera?

I am getting trouble in using dragonfly when I am offline and due to proxy settings I am unable to use Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps instead of looking for alternatives, you should try to get Dragonfly to work. It *should* work offline after an initial online connection which is required to download the latest version, or, if you are unable to do this, it can be downloaded directly from

https://github.com/operasoftware/dragonfly

For more details, see [this dragonfly blog post](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/running-opera-dragonfly-offline), and remember to update the "Developer Tools URL" in `opera:config` to point to the location of your downloaded `client.xml` file instead of the default `https://dragonfly.opera.com/app/` (which would require an active connection) as per [this comment](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/show.dml/34953322#comment102473982).